# Media convertor used to connect locations in same building

Tags: networking, router

So my situation is this, I have a location in the same building on floors 1 and 3 that needs to be connected to the same network.

All the equipment is on floor 1 and I needed to connect floor 3 to the router, for some reason, it was physically impossible to run a cable from one to another, fortunately, the building had optical fiber that I used.

The issue is

I used 2 media convertors to connect the locations.
The starting speed is 1GB but on floor 3 for some reason is limited to 100MB
And sometimes, if not most of the time the connection to the internet seems unresponsive or very low.

What's going on here? Since for example if I access a network resource it works as it should

Comment: What media converters did you use? Are they both 1Gbps? Do they match the type of the fiber? What type of optical fiber did you have?

Comment: yes both of them are 1GB ( https://www.tp-link.com/ro/business-networking/accessory/mc210cs/ ) + https://conectica.ro/retelistica/cabluri-fibra-optica/cablu-fibra-optica-lc-sc-om3-duplex-multimode-1m-roline-21158711 also both are running on the building optical cables I don't know the type of those

Comment: please provide a diagram how the devices are connected physicaly, your description is not clear enough.

Comment: Can you update the question with a picture of the fiber optic cabling? It should also have manufacturing markings on the jacket, and be a specific jacket color for the standardized types. You may just have a mismatch for the laser type that's being used in the media converters.

Comment: So basically the setup goes as follows: Router has 3 ports used, 1 goes to switch 1 , 2 goes to switch 2, 3 goes to media convertor and goes to floor 3 to another media convertor from with the ethernet cable goes to switch 3.  https://prnt.sc/1df55c8